# tasm написать программу

Tags: tasm

Помогите написать программу на TASM.

Нужно создать массив из N чисел. Определить, сколько нулей находится до минимального значения в массиве (если несколько минимальных значений, то минимальным считать последнее значение, если минимальное значение находится в конце массива, то вывести сообщение об этом и прекратить обработку) и среднее арифметическое положительных чисел, находящихся после минимального значения(если положительных чисел нет, то вывести сообщение об этом).

может как то так

```
use16           ;Генерировать 16-битный код
org 100h        ;Программа начинается с адреса 100h
jmp start       ;Безусловный переход на метку start

;----------------------------------------------------------
length  db 10  ;длина массива
array db -1,2,-3,4,5,0,-2,2,8,4  ;массив
;----------------------------------------------------------
start:
mov bx,array   ;В DX адрес строки.
movzx cx,[length]  ;CX = длина массива

xor al,al  ; указатель на 1-й элемент, принятый за начальный минимум
cmp al,[dx] ;сравнение AL и DX
jnc min  ;переход к min если больше
mov al,[dx] ;Поместить DX в регистр Al

min:
inc dx ;увеличение на 1
dec cx ;Уменьшить CX на единицу
jnz start  ;переход к start

exit:
mov ax,4C00h    ;\
int 21h         ;/ Завершение программы
;----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: С чем именно нужна помощь? Надо за вас написать?

Comment: я новичок в этом, пока получилось только массив создать. А как  определить, сколько нулей находится до минимального значения в массиве пока не знаю. Помогите с этим хотя бы.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос. Добавьте в него код ваших попыток и объясните детально суть ваших проблем. Это повысит шансы на помощь.

Comment: Вообще уже не правильно. функция 9 прерывания 21h печатает строку, до завершающего символа `$`. А у вас массив чисел и если вы захотите выводить его на экран вам понадобится процедура перевода чисел из бинарного вида в десятичный (или другой системы счисления) и приведение его к печатным символам. А что основы задачи, берете в регистр первый элемент массива, идете по массиву и сравниваете значение с сохраненным. Если меньше, запоминаете новое и его позицию в массиве. Дойдя до конца вы знаете минамальный элемент и его позицию. проходите по массиву от этой позиции к началу и считаете нули

Comment: Книга "Основы языка Ассемблера", К. Г. Финогенов - ней есть именно то, что вам нужно.